# How can I take a parameter input from the pipeline and force 3 digit numbers?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a parameter input field that a user is able to enter numbers into. I want to limit it to 3 digits and if it is any less, force 3 digits. I have tried "format"-ing it but number seems to be an invalid type for everything I've tried...

```
parameters:
- name: someNums
  type: number
  default: 0
parameters:
- name: rightNums
  value: ${{ format('{0:000}', parameters.someNums) }}
```

I have also tried `{0:D3}` & `{0:###}` & `{0:N2}` to no avail...

This value is needed through a lot of stages that run so I would prefer not to have to do it in each stage (which is why I was trying for variable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid that there is no such method can force the parameter input to 3 digit numbers.

Azure DevOps does not support judging input parameters to force the format of parameters for the time being.

For a workaround, you can add expressions in job/stage/step to check for three  digit numbers to determine if it needs to be run.

Here is an example:

```
parameters:
- name: someNums
  type: number
  default: 0

variables:
  - name: 'environment'
    value: ${{parameters.someNums}}
  - name: test
    value:  ${{ length(variables.environment) }}
steps:
- ${{ if eq(variables['test'], '3') }}:
  - script: echo $(test)
    displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```

I can fully understand your requirement,  you can create a [suggestion feedback](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) to report the feature requirement.

Comment: I marked this answer as correct as it just validated what I suspected: this cannot be done in the pipeline.
Since I care less about the actual length of the variable, and more about formatting, I created a PS script that will take the input variable, convert it to 3 digit string, and generate a new string with additional parameters/variables for use in other stages.